# Language direction in Image-Set isn't taking effect when selecting image in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uistoryboard, uiimageasset

I have an image set whose Direction ([language direction](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/ImageSetType.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015170-CH25-SW32)) property is set to `Left to Right`. This means the image should be mirrored horizontally for right-to-left languages (i.e: Arabic, Hebrew).

[image: Image Set's property]

Now if I set this image on a `UIImageView` from `Storyboard`, the ***image is not mirrored*** for RTL language. See image below:

[image: Image isn't mirrored]

> When *I don't set the image in `imageView` from storyboard* but load
>   the image in code & set it as the `imageView`'s image property the
>   ***image is mirrored*** for RTL language. See image below:

[image: Image is mirrored]

> But again if I set the image in `imageView` from storyboard and load
>   the image in code & set it as the `imageView`'s image property the
>   ***image is not mirrored*** for RTL language. See image below:

[image: Image isn't mirrored again]

### Question:

What's the problem with **just Storyboard only**? And why code can't override the behavior when *image is set from Storyboard and also from code at the same time*?

Answer (score 0):

In your first screenshot, the direction of the images are **Left to Right Mirrors** set them to  **Right to Left, Mirrors**..

Comment: No. That will affect the orientation of the image for LTR language. Because my expected output for LTR is [this](http://imgur.com/YDZOH5q). And I just want to have mirrored image for RTL language.

Comment: Click on 3rd or 4th image. Nothing much from the code side, it's just loading the `image` and filling `imageView` with that `image`